# Special charecters in Windows shows right, in Linux just question marks

Tags: html-encode

Why is that i get letters like š,č,ž written correct in Windows but as question marks in Linux? I'm using UTF8 encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I have also saved file as utf-8 type of file. Could it be because I've created and edited file in Windows?

Comment: I've seen this when the font you're using doesn't support the character you're attempting to use.  Use the font viewer on Linux to see if the character you want is represented in the font you're trying to use.

Comment: It's probably not problem with fonts. I'm using Georga, serif fonts

Comment: Not every font implements the accented characters.  But suit yourself.

Comment: I've turned off those fonts and result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using HTML, here's some straight [HTML codes for Slavic Characters](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cz.htm).

If that doesn't solve the problem, then I've seen this issue in SQL development; JimR is half-correct: the Character, rather than the font, is not supported.

Your *font* doesn't matter so much as your *character set*, i.e. whether or not the character exists in your context. The real question becomes, "Does your current Linux environment support that character in it's character set?"

If you're not sure, try exchanging UTF-8 for [ISO/IEC 8859-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16). A bit more heavy handed, and some extra coding if you need the other characters in UTF-8, but since it's the standard character set for the region surrounding Slovakia, there shouldn't be a reason it wouldn't work.

Should that fail, then the issue is clearly your Linux Distribution in some degree.

Best of luck!